# Effective boxplot (or its variants) for certain types of data

Tags: r, boxplot

I run a bunch of simulations to evaluate type I error, so the result is a vector such as

`pdata = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.07,0,0.02,0.03)`

The mean of the simulated vector should be 0.05. Now I am thinking of a way to display the results via boxplots. The default function in R

`boxplot(pdata)`

gives a boxplot that is rather hard to see the typical value as there are many 0's. In addition, it shows the median, but what I really want is the mean to be displayed on the plot. Are there any graphical display that is effective in such situation? I know that I can simply report the numerical values, but because my simulation involves other factors which I hope to compare, a boxplot-like graph will be ideal. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered a [violin plot](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_violin.html), or, if your values are rounded like that, maybe a [dot plot](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_dotplot.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe :

```
 plot(table(pdata))
```

[image]

Here a ggplot2 version :

```
   ggplot(as.data.frame(table(pdata)),aes(x=pdata,y=Freq))+geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, can I know is there a way to explicitly show on graph the mean of the vector?

Comment: @alittleboy you want to show the mean on this plot or you dont like the idea of the table?

Comment: the idea of using table to group is excellent, but since there are huge number of 0's, I guess in my real data, other points might still be difficult to see. I hope to find a plot that can show the mean of the vector while keeping/summarizing the original data on the same plot.

Comment: @alittleboy I update my version, you can add the mean value as a text?